# Missing Python.h in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman

I use Arch Linux. I want to compile a C++ file that includes `<Python.h>`.
But I can't do it.

In Debian based systems this problem is resolved with `sudo apt-get install python-dev`. How I can install this package with pacman?

*** EDIT ***

I wan't to compile this file

C.c

```
#include "Python.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

run this command:

```
g++ C.c
```

and i have this error:

```
call_function.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Both the python and python2 package in Arch Linux contain a Python.h file, you don't need an extra package. What's the exact error message you're getting and what is your include path?

Comment: I can't compile this `#include<Python.h>` with gcc

Comment: @28 just tell us what Wieland asked you to tell.

Comment: I edit this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should compile your files with libs and cflags provided by python package:

`gcc py.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python2) -o py`

Besides, it should be `#include <Python.h>` instead.

Comment: "gcc py.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -o py" for python3